# Where Buildroot exports configuration symbols

Tags: linux, makefile, embedded-linux, buildroot

I want to know where in the code buildroot exports the configuration symbols so that they can be read in the .mk for each package:

Example:

In the package `exim.mk` there is a test on `BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSL` value:

```
ifeq ($(BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSL),y)
```

The symbol is defined in the `.config`, but how `exim.mk` read it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buildroot is based on the `make` build system. `make` reads in the top-level Makefile, and parses the `include` directives in that file. One such directive is

```
-include $(BR2_CONFIG)
```

The `BR2_CONFIG` variable expands to `.config` (either in the Buildroot directory, or in the output directory if `O=` is given). The `.config` file contains all the configuration options that you selected using the Kconfig infrastructure.

Next, the top-level Makefile has

```
include $(sort $(wildcard package/*/*.mk))
```

This reads in all the `.mk` files in the package directory, including `exim.mk`. So when `exim.mk` is parsed, the `BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSL` value set in `.config` will be evaluated. This can be either

```
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSL=y
```

if the option was selected, or

```
# BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSL is not set
```

if it was not selected. So the condition will be true in the first case and false in the second case.

Comment: OK, Get it Thanks